# How to hide div content securely in Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have this code.
it's working fine,

but the problem is that anyone can simply show this div by (inspecting with chrome js debugger) and as a result anybody can make the submit operation.
so my question, can I hide it securely with jquery ?

Thanks.

```
<div id="submitDiv">
    @using(Html.BeginForm())
    {
      @Html.hidden("hiddenField")
      <button type="submit">Save</button>
    }
</div>

<script>
    $(function () {
        var value=ajaxFunction();

        if(value)
        {
            $("#divSubmit").show();
        }
        else
        {
            $("#divSubmit").hide();
        }
   });

</script>
```

Comment: If I were You, I would use css style display:none for this

Comment: You can not hide anything securely in a web page.

Comment: Everything sent to the client can be viewed by the client somehow.

Comment: No you can't.It is not possible.

Comment: There is no way to hide something in the browser, however you CAN make it rather hard to find. Copy the entire div into a variable and then delete it from the visible dom via `removeChild` method. When need it you can `appendChild` to get it back.

Comment: My first thought was to make, a Partial View and a method in your controller which would return this view. So everytime you will want to show this div you will need to make ajax call for it.

Comment: Everybody is yelling "can't be done" which is completely true, but then again if you do it properly 99% of the people wont be able to find it... I mean... not everybody is a hardcore webdev. Question is, how would you show it, when? Tell me what would be the way for you to show the dialog and I will give you what I belive is a very good solution for you.

Comment: @PawełMikołajczyk Thank you all, I will solve it by using partial views with ajax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a partial view and a method which will return this view in your controller. Then assign an url to this method in your JavaScript code of MVC view like this:

```
var linkToPartialView = '@Url.Action('NameOfMethod', 'NameOfController')';
```

Now, when you will need to show your view you will make an ajax call with this url:

```
$.ajax({
  url: linkToPartialView 
}).done(function (html) {
  $('#divSubmit').append(html);
});
```

When you will want to hide it, just remove its content:

```
$('#divSubmit').children().remove();
```

Answer (score 1):

Everything sent to the client can be viewed by the client somehow. There is no way for securely hiding information (you might encrypt it, but it's still there somehow, possible options could be to store some information in a server side session).

That's also the reason why all security related checks needs to be done on the server (e.g., a client who disabled javascript or just bypassed all checks locally) and data fro the client must not be trusted.

Answer (score 1):

It can't be done with Html / CSS / JQuery as anything client side can be changed.

You will need to add something to your server side code and just not show it if it's not meant to be be.

Something like:

```
@if (Model.CanShow)
{
    <div id="submitDiv">
        @using(Html.BeginForm())
        {
          @Html.hidden("hiddenField")
          <button type="submit">Save</button>
        }
    </div>
}
```

Note: I've provided a C# code example as I see you're using ASP.NET MVC.

Comment: Even then, validate in the submission code (on the server) whether the user is allowed to do that. Trust *nothing* from the browser.

Comment: thanks for answering, I had this in my mind, but the problem is that I am depending on ajax function result, I don't want to reload the view.

Comment: In that case, see Pawel's answer as that will do what you want

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript run in client side so every this you hide can be seen ,you need to control this via server side language like php , C#/MVC/Webforms ... because the can control the output html

```
@if (false)
{
    <div>
        Hidden things
    </div>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**[This](https://jsfiddle.net/r7q6y256/2/)**  (fiddle link)
is as "secure" as you are going to get. Nobody can inspect the element or access the function that shows it as it is wrapped into an event handler in my case, in your case it would be wrapped to an event you need. This sort of "protection" cannot be broken by 99% of the web developers, I for one don't know how I would break it, I would like to see anybody here show how.

**Edit:** added even more protection

```
//Register the handler to the event you want to have show the submit form
//You can just add this to anything you want... i chose a button because.. .reasons, you probably
//want some checkbox or timed event to check if you filled out your form
document.getElementById("enableForm").addEventListener('click',
  (function() {
    var submitForm = document.createElement('div');
    var submitButton = document.createElement('button');
    submitButton.innerHTML = "Submit";
    submitButton.addEventListener('click', submit);
    submitForm.innerHTTML = "<p>This is a form</p>";
    submitForm.appendChild(submitButton);
    var extraProtection = false;

    function ShowSubmitForm() {
      var parent = document.getElementById("formParent").appendChild(submitForm);
    }

    function ShowFormHandler() {
      //Make a function that handles when to show the form

      ShowSubmitForm();      
    }

    function submit() {
        alert("Protected submit");
    }

    return ShowFormHandler;
  })()
);
```

Comment: Surely they just delete the content of the script that is registering this event within the console window? That or get the HTML you're injecting and insert it using the element inspector then submit as normal ...

Comment: If you delete the content you cannot get the form, as nothing is ever registering it, thus that premise is discarded.... as for the second HTML can be read from the script but you could just write it up then. You cannot get a reference to the HTML that is being injected in the page inspector, it is wrapped in a function closure. Thus you cannot do `document.getElementById('parent').addChild(submitForm);` you'd get undefined. You can write up a form and add it... but this is not really the same as having OP's form. Only issue, the event handler.

Comment: No part of this is exposed to the user as it is wrapped in a function, cannot be referenced. If you want an extra layer of protection, add another variable, with a condition to the annonymus function that is set to false, never triggering the submit unless he sets it to true. Arguing that someone can look at the HTML mockup in the code then write the exact same mockup and use that to submit is arguing someone can copy your website and use that website to submit, he cannot access or reference the elements within that closure of the anno function.

Answer (score -1):

you can do this instead if you do not need that div:

```
else
        {
            $("#divSubmit").remove();
        }
```